# How to pivot googlefinance() horizontally?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

In Google Sheets, is there a way to pivot the output of googlefinance() horizontally? Currently, it outputs prices/dates vertically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use TRANSPOSE(),

```
=TRANSPOSE(googlefinance())
```

[image]

is that what you where up to?